# Sum of Kloosterman sums bound by $O(n^{\epsilon})$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I've been studying the book "Topics in Classical Automorphic forms" by Henryk Iwaniec and I am stuck at a bound.
For even $k$ and any $3/4 < \sigma < 1$ the book claims the following for the Kloosterman sum $S(n,n,c)$ where $\epsilon>0 $ is fixed, as $n$ gets large. (page 73)

$$\sum_{c>0} c^{-2\sigma}|S(n,n,c)| \ll n^{\epsilon} $$

I've been trying to prove this using the Weyl bound $|S(m,n,c)| \le \gcd(m,n,c)^{1/2} c^{1/2}\tau(c)$ but I haven't managed to do so. Maybe I am missing something basic but in order to create a convergent series the bounds for the $\tau$ function seems to exceed any hopes I have for that.

Comment: @reuns This question is not directly about modular forms, but it is indirectly, since sums of Kloosterman sums appear in the Petersson formula and the Kuznetsov formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|S(n,n;c)| \leq (n,c)^{1/2} c^{1/2} \tau(c)$ and $\tau(c) \ll_{\varepsilon} c^{\varepsilon}$, this sum is
$$\ll_{\varepsilon} \sum_{c = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(n,c)^{1/2}}{c^{2\sigma - 1/2 - \varepsilon}}.$$
Now write this sum over $c \in \mathbb{N}$ as a double sum over $m \mid n$ and over $c \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $(c,n) = m$ (that is, break up the sum over $c$ based on the $\gcd$ of $c$ and $n$). Having done this, make the change of variables $c \mapsto mc$, since $(c,n) = m$ implies that $m \mid c$. We get
$$\sum_{m \mid n} \frac{1}{m^{2\sigma - 1 - \varepsilon}} \sum_{\substack{c = 1 \\ (c,\frac{n}{m}) = 1}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{c^{2\sigma - 1/2 - \varepsilon}}.$$
The inner sum over $c$ converges absolutely since $\sigma > 3/4$. The outer sum is $\ll_{\varepsilon} n^{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was really helpful and detailed. I just have one question about the inner sum which converges absolutely. I am not sure why that holds true since $\epsilon$ may be arbitrary large. For instance if n=m and $\epsilon > 2\sigma-3/2$ the series seem to diverge if I am not mistaken.

Comment: No, epsilon is tiny.

Comment: Ah yes. Doesn't make any sense to look for large $\epsilon$ since we want the best bound. Thank you once again.